# Reverse the order of the result set in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, select

This could be a very basic problem, but I sort of don't know SQL at all.

To simplify the problem, let there be a table with only one column, so I can write down the rows horizontally:

```
1 3 11 39 41 45 52 63 66 70 72 80 81 90 92 97
```

As you can see, they are sorted. Now, I know there is the row with "70", and I want to query five rows before it in ascending order. That is, I want

```
41 45 52 63 66
```

How should I do the query?

I can query the five rows in descending order and reverse the result set afterwards, but I think there should be a better way.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Taking [likeToCode's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529764/reverse-the-order-of-the-result-set-in-sqlite/10531127#10531127), just modify it as follows, to reorder the result:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM SAMPLE
    WHERE index1 < 70
    ORDER BY index1 DESC
    LIMIT 0,5
)
ORDER BY index1 ASC;
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is the query that I was able to come up with, but I am not sure whether this is what you require and moreover the result is in descending order.

I created a table, SAMPLE, with index1 as its only column:

```
SELECT * FROM SAMPLE WHERE index1 < 70 ORDER BY index1 DESC LIMIT 0,5;
```

Comment: That's why my question called "reverse the order of result set". I only know how to query it in descending order.